# jQuery Ajax load HTML content with image, how to check whether all images are loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

I'm doing a script for infinite scroll for my site:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    ...
    $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function(json) {if(json.success){
        ...
        // here I append an Ajax @response with a new element to my existing HTML
        $("#mindIndexSummaryFirst").append(json.items1);
        $("#mindIndexSummarySecond").append(json.items2);
        $("#mindIndexSummaryThird").append(json.items3);
        // here I try to check whether all images are loaded
        $("#mindIndexSummary img").on('load', function(){
          // and I need to call two functions on loaded element
          // hoverImg() need the loaded image to calculate the height
          $('.pi-hover-img'+json.course).hoverImg();
          $(".popup3").tooltip();
        });
      }
    ...
  });
```

A loaded HTML element is this:

```
<div class="page-item pi-hover-img  pi-normal">
  <a class="overlayPop" href="#">
  <a class="item_uri" id="course153" href="#">
    <img src="/public/file/course/image/153-course.png" class="pi-item-image">
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="popup5 hide-text" style="display: none;">
    <img src="/public/file/account/image/282-user.jpeg" class="item_image">
  </a>
  <a class="popup action-button big_interested " id="course_153" href="javascript:;" style="top: -162.5px; left: 83.5px; display: none;"> Mi interessa</a>
  <a href="javascript:;">Description</a>
  <a class="popup4 hide-text" href="javascript:;">Preview</a>
  <span class="popup2" style="display: none;">1€</span>
  <a href="/course/153/gestire-un-pubblico">
    <h2 style="top: 320px;">Gestire un pubblico</h2>
    <span class="rfloat pi-icon">
      <img src="/public/img/site_icon/video_course_black.png">
    </span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I load 5 elements, 15 images, but there is a possibility that fewer elements are loaded.

The problem is that my function was called more than one time (I test this with alert) and I'm not sure secure that the function was called after image load.

If someone had the same situation please suggest me something (P.S I apologize for my bad English).

Comment: The on-load event handler isn't working for you?

Comment: load will fire for every image load( $("#mindIndexSummary img").length times)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#mindIndexSummary img").on('load', function(){ });
```

Will attach the handler to each of the images that match the query - so each image will fire the function when it is loaded - not once when all are finished loading.

You would have to keep track of the images that have loaded in order to say whether they have all loaded.

Along the lines of:

```
var noOfImages = $("#mindIndexSummary img").length;
var noLoaded = 0;

$("#mindIndexSummary img").on('load', function(){ 

    noLoaded++;
    if(noOfImages === noLoaded) {
        handleAllLoaded();
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I solve the problem with some changes of your code: 
When i load a new elements i put in it another id  $('.pi-hover-img'+json.course) "json.course" what change on any new loaded elements.

Infact if i check for all images $("#mindIndexSummary img").length; i have a number of al images loaded previus to. But i need the number of newer loaded images, and i can get this number with my id that i add: var noOfImages = $('.pi-hover-img'+json.course+" img").length;

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough version of a solution I've used in a similar situation. `numLoaded` is updated each time the `load` method is executed, which allows you to check if the forecast ( `numImage` ) is equal to the total amount of images loaded.

```
var img =  $( '#mindIndexSummary' ).find( 'img' )
  , numImage = img.length;

img.on( 'load', function(){

    var self = $( this )
      , numLoaded  = self.attr( 'data-loaded', true ).length;

    self.attr( 'data-loaded', true );

    if( numImages === numLoaded ) 

    funcToCall();   


});
```

Also, you can go one step further and set a `data` attribute on the parent element, which would allow you to trigger/terminate other events based on its value.

```
var parent = $( '#mindIndexSummary' )
  , img =  $( '#mindIndexSummary' ).find( 'img' )
  , numImage = img.length;

img.on( 'load', function(){

    var self = $( this )
      , numLoaded  = self.attr( 'data-loaded', true ).length;

    parent.attr( 'data-load', 'loading' );
    self.attr( 'data-loaded', true );

    if( numImages === numLoaded ) 

    parent.attr( 'data-load', 'complete' );
    funcToCall();   


});

if( parent.attr('data-load').slice( 0, 7 ) === 'loading' )
do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Load event on images is a bit unreliable (see Jquery docs at http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).
That said, it's possible to assemble a solution by checking individually for load event on every selected image. Chances are that an image is cached or already loaded at time of execution. In this case the image element should have a ".complete" attribute.

I made a small jQuery plugin that illustrates the approach (there are more complete ones anyway):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.imagesLoaded = function(options) {
        var images = this.find("img"), 
            loadedImages = [], 
            options = options;

        images.each(function(i, image) {
            function loaded() {
                loadedImages.push(this);
                if(options.imageLoaded) {
                    options.imageLoaded(this);    
                }
                if(loadedImages.length == images.length) {
                    if(options.complete) {
                        options.complete(loadedImages);    
                    }
                }
            }

            if(image.complete || image.complete === undefined) {
                // Image is already loaded
                loaded.call(image);               
            } else {
                // Image is not loaded yet, bind event
                $(image).load(loaded);
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

The plugin accepts a hash with two callbacks, one firing each time an image is loaded (the image gets passed as a parameter), the other when all images have loaded (the array of images gets passed as a parameter).

```
$("#element-containing-images").imagesLoaded({
    imageLoaded: function(image) {
       console.log("Image loaded:", image); 
    }, 
    complete: function(images) {
        console.log("All images loaded:", images);
    }
});
```

It's not complete with all the quirks, but it should give you a general idea.
I made a small demo available at http://jsfiddle.net/GYJGK/.

Answer (score 0):

This is a description of how to create a global variable (an array) that will keep track of each individual image that is loaded. This way you can actively check when all images are loaded using callback functions.

```
var image_state_array = new Array(false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
```

Each position in the array will keep track of which image has been loaded. So for example if image 2 in the list of 10 images has been loaded the array would look like this (remember array indexes start at 0):

```
var image_state_array = new Array(false, false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
```

Lets say you have a list of images that you are dynamically reloading based on some user interaction (for instance the user clicks refresh to get a new set of images to choose from). Once all of the images have loaded you want to alert the user that the images have loaded (or call some other sort of function). Start by first setting up an onload event for the image that is about to be loaded.

```
//get image 0

var image = document.getElementsByClassName("search_images")[0];

//track the image load state 

image.onload = function(){
      trackImageLoadState(0); //note that 0 is the image index from the list of elements 
}
```

Next set the source of the image as you usually would. This will trigger the onload even and call the function.

```
//set the source of the image, 

    image.src = desireImagePNG;
```

The track image load state will add that the image has loaded to the image_state_array, tracking that image0 has loaded. After it records that image0 has loaded, it loops through the image_state_array and counts how many of the returned images have loaded. If the enough images have loaded it executes whatever function you were trying to achieve. In this example I am fading out a loading screen.

```
    function trackImageLoadState(numImage){
      //debug print
      //console.log("numImage: " + numImage);

      //set the array image value to true of the passed in index 
      image_state_array[numImage] = true;

      //debug print
      //console.log("image_state_array[numImage] " + image_state_array[numImage] );

      var loadedImagesCount = 0;

      //loop through the array and count the amount of images that have loaded
      for(var counter2 = 0; counter2 < image_state_array.length; counter2++){
        //debug print
        //console.log("image_state_array[counter] " + image_state_array[counter2] + "counter" + counter2 );

        if(image_state_array[counter2]){
          loadedImagesCount++;
        }
      }

      //debug print
      //console.log("loadedImagesCount: " + loadedImagesCount);

      //if the amount of images required to be loaded has been met, execute function. If you want to know when all images have been loaded, you need to set the if statement condition to the total count of images. For example:
if(loadedImagesCount>10){} if you have 10 images. 

  if(loadedImagesCount>5){

    //fade out the loading screen - any other function will work here as well
    fadeOutMainLoadingScreen();

  }

}
```

Keep in mind that the global variable will have to be reset everytime the action is called again. This can done as shown below:

```
//reset the global variable array to track the new load of images 

for(var i = 0; i < image_state_array.length; i++){
  image_state_array[i] = false;
}
```

This is an effective way to track which images have loaded via a callback function and a global variable. Please comment as I know it could probably be improved and made more dynamic. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks man! But in my context i prefer to use jquery or something that track the entire loading, because i can not know or need to do something for know the number of images i have to load.